# show Enable/disable value on grid list magento

Tags: magento-1.9

In Magento 1.9, I have created Module and in admin grid i want to show value 0/1 as Enable/Disable title. But it is not working. Here is my script which i am using.

```
$this->addColumn('status',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Status'),
            'align' =>'right',
            'width' => '50px',
            'index' => 'status',
            'options' => array('1'=>'Enable','0'=>'Disable')
        )
    );
```

Please anybody can help me where i need to change in Grid.php file.
Thank you

Comment: Anybody can help me, I searched into so much but it is not working. Your help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I solved it my self.

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->addColumn('is_active', [
            'header'=> __('status'),
            'align' => 'left',
            'index' => 'is_active',
            'params' => ['id'=>'getId'],
            'type'      => 'options',
            'options'   => array(
                1 => 'enabled',
                0 => 'disabled',
            ),
        ]);
```